# Date validation in a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code that gets a date from the user MM-DD-YYYY and validates that it is that format and then converts it to YYYY-MM-DD.  Everything works right...mostly.  However, I cannot figure out why when it gets to the YYYY part it stops validating.  It is probably missing some code to check that.

```
:sof
GOTO :ValidDate

:: Get and validate date
:ValidDate
SET i=0
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   SET /A i+=1
   SET dpm[!i!]=%%a
)

SET /P "inDate=First Contact Date (MM-DD-YYYY format): "
if "%inDate:~2,1%%inDate:~5,1%" neq "--" GOTO invalidDate
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ("%inDate%") do SET "MM=%%a" & SET "DD=%%b" & SET "YYYY=%%c"
ver > NUL
SET /A month=1%MM%-100, day=1%DD%-100, year=1%YYYY%-10000, leap=year%%4  2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 GOTO invalidDate
if not defined dpm[%month%] GOTO invalidDate
if %leap% equ 0 SET dpm[2]=29
if %day% gtr !dpm[%month%]! GOTO invalidDate
if %day% lss 1 GOTO invalidDate
ECHO.
ECHO.
GOTO :loopCompanyType

:invalidDate
ECHO Date input is invalid.  Fomat must be MM-DD-YYYY.
ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO :sof
```

Here is the code I originally had for month+day+year and combine but couldn't get to validate either.

```
:ValidateDate
ECHO.
SET /P month="Please enter First Contact Month (format must be MM)
ECHO.
IF [%month:~2%] NEQ [] echo Month format entered incorrectly.  Try again. & GOTO :ValidateDate
SET /P day="Please enter First Contact Day (format must be DD)
ECHO.
IF [%day:~2%] NEQ [] echo Day format entered incorrectly.  Try again. & GOTO :ValidateDate
SET /P year="Please enter First Contact Year (format must be YYYY)
ECHO.
IF [%month:~4%] NEQ [] echo Year format entered incorrectly.  Try again. & GOTO :ValidateDate
SET FCD=%year%-%month%-%day%
CHOICE /C YN /M "Is the First Contact Date %FCD% correct?"
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO :ValidateDate
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO :loopCompanyType
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. For instance, I don't understand the _when it gets to the YYYY part it stops validating_ assertion. What happens?

Comment: Just be aware that the `--` check will only confirm that the user entered those two characters, in those two positions. it doesn't verify that the correct number of characters were entered, or that the non `-` characters were all integers.

Comment: My initial thought is that if it isn't too much of an inconvenience to your end users, to ask for the year, then the month, then the day, and check each as you go, when you're satisfied that they are all valid, join them yourself as necessary.

Comment: @JosefZ You can input MM-DD-Y and it accepts it as valid.  It needs to verify that YYYY is the correct format.

Comment: @Compo I did try something like this initial.  I originally got this script going back in 2013.  I'm not the greatest at batch and just recently realized it was broken.  I went with the original code I posted above because it was less prompts for the user.  I also could never get the month+day+year then combine to validate right.  Edited to show my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *You can input `MM-DD-Y` and it accepts it as valid. It needs to verify that `YYYY` is the correct format.*

You can extend the "`--`" test as follows:

```
SET /P "inDate=First Contact Date (MM-DD-YYYY format): "
set "inDateX=%inDate%-bcde"
if "%inDateX:~2,1%%inDateX:~5,1%%inDateX:~10,1%" neq "---" GOTO invalidDate
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ("%inDate%") do (
    SET "MM=%%a"
    SET "DD=%%b"
    SET "YYYY=%%c"
)
```

**OOPS!**
There is another tease (with the following `echo`s at the `:loopCompanyType` label):

```
:loopCompanyType
ECHO. set  %inDate%
ECHO. comp %yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%
```

Possible undisclosed wrong input: `.\SO\62959167.bat`

> ```
> First Contact Date (MM-DD-YYYY format): 12-31-20-0
>  set  12-31-20-0
>  comp 20-12-31
> ```

### Solution

Utilize [FINDSTR](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) support for regular expressions.

**Edit**. Updated according to beneficial Compo's comment on `cmd` poisonous characters e.g. `>`, `&`, `|` etc.
Given *full script* used for testing; I hope that it's almost bullet-proof code snippet now. :)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:sof
GOTO :ValidDate

:: Get and validate date
:ValidDate
SET i=0
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   SET /A i+=1
   SET dpm[!i!]=%%a
)

SET /P "inDate=First Contact Date (MM-DD-YYYY format): "
set "inDateX=%inDate%-bcde"
if "%inDateX:~2,1%%inDateX:~5,1%%inDateX:~10,1%" neq "---" GOTO invalidDate
(call )
echo("%inDate%"|findstr "^\"[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\"$">NUL
if errorlevel 1 GOTO invalidDate
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ("%inDate%") do (
    SET "MM=%%a"
    SET "DD=%%b"
    SET "YYYY=%%c"
)
ver > NUL
SET /A month=1%MM%-100, day=1%DD%-100, year=1%YYYY%-10000, leap=year%%4  2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 GOTO invalidDate
if not defined dpm[%month%] GOTO invalidDate
if %leap% equ 0 SET dpm[2]=29
if %day% gtr !dpm[%month%]! GOTO invalidDate
if %day% lss 1 GOTO invalidDate
GOTO :loopCompanyType

:invalidDate
ECHO "%inDate%" Date input is invalid.  Format must be MM-DD-YYYY.
ECHO.
REM PAUSE
GOTO :sof

:loopCompanyType
ECHO. set  %inDate%
ECHO. comp %yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%
```

**Output**: `.\SO\62959167.bat`

> ```
> First Contact Date (MM-DD-YYYY format): 12-19-9¹³9
> "12-19-9¹³9" Date input is invalid.  Fomat must be MM-DD-YYYY.
>
> First Contact Date (MM-DD-YYYY format): 12-19-9<&9
> "12-19-9<&9" Date input is invalid.  Fomat must be MM-DD-YYYY.
>
> First Contact Date (MM-DD-YYYY format): 12-19-9139
>  set  12-19-9139
>  comp 9139-12-19
> ```

Note [Dave Benham's reply to *setting ERRORLEVEL to 0* question](https://superuser.com/a/649329/376602) (an alternative to `ver>NUL`):

> If you want to force the errorlevel to 0, then you can use this
> totally non-intuitive, but very effective syntax: `(call )`. The space
> after *call* is critical. If you want to set the errorlevel to 1, you
> can use `(call)`. It is critical that there not be any space after
> *call*.

BTW, there are years divisible by 4 which are not [leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm)…

Comment: If the end user was to enter `19-39-9¹³9` as their date, it will pass as valid using your new `findstr` based solution. Not to mention what happens if they were to enter say a `&` or a `|`. I'll also assume that whilst using a `>` or `<` character may not pass as a valid date, that it may try to write to a file and/or generate an error.

Comment: @Compo `findstr` secured against `cmd` special characters **except** a double quote… User's input `12-19-19"9` (or alike) throws _The syntax of the command is incorrect._ (An acceptable risk?)

Comment: Thank you so much @JosefZ & @Compo!!!  Works flawlessly as needed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the suggestion I made in the comments.

The end user is asked for the year, then the month, then the day, each is validated and only when all have been entered correctly, the code continues. I have made it so that it doesn't matter too much what the end user enters, *(except perhaps for some strange <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> sequences)*.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:AskYear
ClS
Set "YYYY="
Set /P "YYYY=Please enter a four digit year from 1970 to 2020 incl e.g. 2016 >"
Set YYYY 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe^
 /R "^YYYY=19[789][0123456789]$ ^YYYY=20[01][0123456789]$ ^YYYY=2020$">NUL^
 ||GoTo AskYear

:AskMonth
ClS
Set "MM="
Set /P "MM=Please enter a two digit month e.g. 04 >"
Set MM 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /R "^MM=0[123456789]$ ^MM=1[012]$">NUL^
 ||GoTo AskMonth

:GetDays
Set "DM=^DD=0[123456789]$ ^DD=[12][0123456789]$ ^DD=3[01]$"
For %%G In (04 06 09 11
)Do If "%%G" == "%MM%" Set "DM=^DD=0[123456789]$ ^DD=[12][0123456789]$ ^DD=30$"
If "%MM%" == "02" (Set "DM=^DD=0[123456789]$ ^DD=[12][012345678]$ ^DD=19$"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&Set /A $=YYYY%%4
    If "!$!" == "0" (EndLocal&Set "DM=^DD=0[123456789]$ ^DD=[12][0123456789]$"
    )Else EndLocal)

:AskDay
ClS
Set "DD="
Set /P "DD=Please enter a two digit day e.g. 08 >"
Set DD 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /R "%DM%">NUL||GoTo AskDay

Echo(%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD% is a valid date&Pause
```

*Obviously the last line is just a confirmation that a valid date was entered, and to show it put together. You would change that to your own code.*